# "illegal byte sequence" even with LC_ALL=C

Tags: macos, filesystem

My understanding is that setting the C locale turns off any encoding/decoding of characters. Somehow, I'm still getting an "illegal byte sequence" error.

```bash
% LC_ALL=C xxd ~/Library/Metadata/CoreSpotlight/NSFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen/index.spotlightV3/journalAttr.1
xxd: /Users/ccottingham/Library/Metadata/CoreSpotlight/NSFileProtectionCompleteUnlessOpen/index.spotlightV3/journalAttr.1: Illegal byte sequence
```

How can the file contain an illegal byte sequence if there *are* no illegal byte sequences in the locale?